# Team foundation server auto build

Tags: visual-studio, tfsbuild

We have a large non Visual Studio C++ project which is build via a batch file.  I have integrated this up in Visual Studio as a makefile project with customised 'Build Command Line' in the project properties, this works well and has done for over a year.

I am now looking to introduce Team Foundation Server and configure automated builds.

If I build the project in Visual Studio then the project build as normal.
If I use the automated build sever to build the project the build fails every time

The option to view the log file in the build report is greyed out.  The report given is

*The command "Autobuild.cmd" exited with code 1.*

Where autobuild is the cmd file specified in the solution's 'Build Command Line'.

Can anyone think of a reason why this might be the case, I assumed that the build sever would just run the Build command with the project specified in the 'Items to Build' box.  If this is the case then I cannot see why it would fail.

Answer (score 1):

There are loads of possible reasons; unfortunately you've not given enough information to answer that questions.

The first thing to try is changing your build definition logging level to `Diagnostic`. (you can also do this when you queue a new build).

What I also recommend is actually wrapping your makefile in an msbuild.proj file.

Something simple like:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="build"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="build">
    <Exec Command="autobuild.cmd" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

The [Exec task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms124737.aspx) has loads of options to customize how the cmd is called and should help you diagnose your error.

In general if you want to take advantaged of TFS builds I'd recommend migrating as much of your autobuild.cmd to msbuild as possible. MSBuild is TFS's "makefile" language, so-to-speak.

Answer (score 0):

In your build definition you have an option of logging, there you can change that to `Verbose` logging. Maybe you get some information in your log file then.

And for the issue of exited with code 1 I think you will need to add some extra informational lines to be printed in the cmd program and when your logging in TFS Build is active you maybe see more information on it.